# How to Add text to the start of all comment?

Tags: comments, tags

I have comment.php in my template but when i change it not effect

What's problem?

I want add Welcome to + title of post + continue text .....

```
<?php
// You can start editing here -- including this comment!
if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h2 class="comments-title">
        <?php
        $comments_number = get_comments_number();
        if ( '1' === $comments_number ) {
            /* translators: %s: post title */
            printf( _x( 'One thought to &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'comments title', 'sparkling' ), get_the_title() );
        } else {
            printf(
                /* translators: 1: number of comments, 2: post title */
                _nx(
                    '%1$s thought to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    '%1$s thoughts to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    $comments_number,
                    'comments title',
                    'sparkling'
                ),
                number_format_i18n( $comments_number ),
                get_the_title()
            );
        }
        ?>
    </h2>

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'sparkling' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="nav-links">

            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'sparkling' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'sparkling' ) ); ?></div>

        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
    <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'style'      => 'ol',
                'short_ping' => true,
                'avatar_size' => 60,
            ) );
        ?>
    </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'sparkling' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="nav-links">

            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'sparkling' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'sparkling' ) ); ?></div>

        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
    <?php
    endif; // Check for comment navigation.

endif; // Check for have_comments().

// If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="no-comments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'sparkling' ); ?></p>
<?php
endif;

comment_form();
?>
```

function addText() { 
        var input = document.getElementById('comment');
        input.value = 'lots of new text ' + input.value;
    }



Comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this filter hook to add this

```
apply_filters( 'pre_comment_content', string $comment_content );
```

Here is the code how you can use this

```
function add_custom_comment_content( $comment_content ) {

    // You can handle it many ways 
    $comment_content .= "Custom Content"
}
add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'add_custom_comment_content', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Where is apply_filters ? I not found in my source code

Comment: @moh3en Use the below code I gave

Comment: I copy and past your code in comment.php but get error in comment in my site Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /localhost/wp-content/themes/sparkling/comments.php on line 120

Answer (score 0):

> apply_filters( 'pre_comment_content', string $comment_content );

Where is apply_filters ? I not found in my source code